# Continuously synchronizing facebook friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In our application users can synchronize his friends based on facebook relationships. User hit "sync" button in application, we call "friends" in graph api, and receive all user that use our application and synchronize friends in our application.

Is there a way to synchronize continuously his friends periodically, for example once a week, without user participation(no need to hit the button)?

Comment: As long as you have valid user access tokens stored ... sure, why not?

Comment: You can also have Facebook notify your app automatically via Webhooks. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/user/#friends

Comment: Is it ok if I will do this for example for 10000 users?

Comment: Depends; if you try this for 10k users you might need to spread it out over a longer period of time, otherwise you might quickly run into the rate limits. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting